# Buzzing sound on first two fret when playing G string on Electric Guitar

Tags: electric-guitar, buzz

I started playing electric guitar for about 1 week now so I'm pretty new to this stuff

The problem here is when I play G string on first or second fret there is buzzing sound
The rest of frets or string are fine
The open G sounds OK unless you hit it relatively hard and you here the buzzing sound again.
So what can I do for this?

Answer (score 1):

Raise the saddle that's under the 3rd string. There will be two little grub screws that need turning, until the buzz goes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say there isn't enough info to diagnose.  There may be issues with a fret coming up.  If there is an uneven bump in the frets this may cause buzzing for just one or two notes on one string.  Does the 1st and 2nd fret buzz for the other strings too?

Is your guitar new of older, used?  If new then it may need an adjustment, bridge and truss rod (which I don't recommend doing on your own w/o experience).  If it's old look for indentations on the frets.  If there are some then you have uneven wear on the frets and that requires the frets to be filed down, possibly replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Do you only notice this when playing without an amp? I was once advised by a luthier at a local guitar shop that electric guitars are designed to be played through amplifiers. As such, it's not "fair" to judge slight string buzzing when played without amplification. Do you notice the buzz when playing with moderate amplification?